# Hide a column on a custom list from non admins

Tags: list, permissions

When you create a new item is there a way to hide a field on the new item form? I have a status field which I dont want the user to fill in. I only want an admin user to be able to change the status. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

A few options that come to my mind are using InfoPath to create a customized form.  Using rules and web services, you could look up the user membership and if the user was part of a specific group, show the column (hiding it for everyone else).

Or you could create a custom form in SharePoint Designer.  Using some XSLT manipulation/multiple templates, you'd be able to display different forms depending on the logic build into the data form web part.

Or you could use some jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) to check the user group similar to above and use CSS to toggle the row.

Or you could enable the management of content types and mark the admin only field as hidden.  This will remove it from all forms and then admins can manage the value of the column using views in datasheet mode.

To edit a field in a content type, go into the List Settings and you should see all the content types being used in the Content Types section.  If not, go into the Advanced Settings and tick the Allow mamangement content types to Yes.  When the screen refreshes, click on the desired content type, then click the desired field and toggle the Column Setting to Hidden.

Comment: How can I mark an field as hidden on a content type?

Comment: Updated answer with steps.

Comment: +1 for list of options and especially for the last, tricky one :) But can't resist to mention, that jQuery/SPServices approach is not secure, so if an ordinary user really **wants** to change status of an item, he can actually do it easily.

Comment: Right, it's just CSS manipulation.

Comment: Added the other possibility, custom form in SharePoint Designer, which would solve the "security" issue as it would all be rendered server side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post showing how to make this done with SharePoint Designer
http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=676af157-7d96-4e15-a987-54b8a3e4d948&ID=3

you can also use this free add-on - http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=SmartListLite

Comment: SharePoint Designer link is broken

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish it by [SharePoint Forms Designer](http://spform.com), just create different forms for specified SharePoint groups using drag&drop interface.